# Как отследить, что мышь находится на определенном виджете?

Tags: c++, qt

Мне нужно, чтобы при перетаскивании вкладки, я мог отследить, находится ли курсор внутри зеленой области, то есть именно на панели вкладок. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, как только пользователь тянет вкладку и курсор выходит за пределы этой зеленой области, происходит вывод в отладку qDebug(); Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться таким решением, но, наверняка, оно не самое лучшее:

```
void yourWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
    if (this->rect().contains(event->pos())) 
    {
        // зарегистрировали нахождение курсора
        // в данной области
    }
}
```

В другом виджете - аналогично, и смотрите - был ли установлен флаг, свидетельствующий о том, что до этого курсор был в области `yourWidget`.
Возможно, остальные виджеты придется сгруппировать в отдельном контейнере.

Comment: А для чего нужен флаг, свидетельствующий о том, что курсор был в области виджета?

Comment: @Nik, да как вариант. Как это будет в коде - это уже Ваше дело )

Comment: Так я спрашиваю зачем нужен этот флаг?

Comment: @Nik, в примере кода даже написано )) В описании )) Что я такого непонятного написал ?)

Comment: Всё, разобрался. Не могли бы уточнить еще по теме. например у меня 2 окна. В каждом по кнопке. Если взять и потащить за кнопку, перемещается всё окно. Как можно отследить, при перемещении окна таким способом, что оно попало в определенную область второго окна?

Comment: @Nik, оба окна имеют общий родительский процесс ?

Comment: Да, оба в одном процессе.

Comment: И еще вопрос: приложение кроссплатформенное ?

Comment: Если под OS Windows - то, зная хэндлы окон, можно получить их геометрию относительно экрана. Думаю, найти пересечение двух прямоугольников - дело не сложное. А еще, в Qt есть такая штука, кажется, QAccessable, она позволяет заюзать потом не только хэндлы окон, но и элементов, содержашихся в этом окне.

Comment: А платформонезависимых решений не существует? Ведь такой механизм применяется во многих программах, неужели все так костыльно.. Конечный результат я описал в комментарии к ответу ниже.

Comment: В принципе, уверен, что Qt предоставляет информацию о местоположении окна (элемента), но выявление "пересечения" все же лежит на плечах программиста.

Comment: А если например узнавать глобальные координаты нужной области другого окна и потом через `contains()` отслеживать внутри мы или нет, это будет быдлокод?

Answer (score 0):

Та часть, которая вам нужна, называется [QTabBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html). И у неё уже есть свойство `movable`, разрешающее перетаскивание вкладок.

Соответственно, вместо создания наследника QTabWidget, достаточно выполнить следующий вызов для уже имеющегося элемента управления:

```
yourTabs.tabBar()->setMovable(true);
```

---

**P. S.:** правильно я понимаю, что конечной целью является создание многодкументного интерфейса с отдельным документом на каждой вкладке? Может быть, тогда имеет смысл воспользоваться специально предназначенным для этого [QMdiArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html), выставив ему свойства `documentMode` и `tabsMovable`?

Comment: Я знаю про это свойство, но вопрос не об этом. Я хочу, чтобы при помощи свойства `movable();` вкладки можно было двигать(менять порядок), но если потянуть вкладки за пределы `QTabBar`'a, чтобы срабатывало другое событие. Конечная цель - получить вкладки как в браузерах(или в Visual Studio) - можно менять порядок вкладок, если потянуть вкладку за пределы, образуется новое окно, и если потянуть окно обратно, оно станет вкладкой.И да, для многодокументного интерфейса. Насколько я знаю, в `MDIArea` такой встроенной возможности нет.